# How to use predicate with JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nspredicate

I'm learning iOS and I would like to create in my `RootViewController`, `SearchBar` and SearchDisplay Controller, I want show in `SearchBar` my expression from JSON(url). I have problem with `NSPredicate` predicateWithFormat.
Below is my code:

```
-(void)searchThroughData{
self.results = nil;
NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"expression", self.searchBar.text];
self.results = [[self.finalResultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];}
```

JSON(url) file:

```
{phrase:
[
{
    expression: "ios",
    meaning: "bla bla bla bla bla"
    },
{
    expression: "objc",
    meaning: "Hello Stack"
    }
]
}
```

How can I use to `NSPredicate` ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *fileterArray= [self.finalResultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.%@ contains[c] %@ ,@"expression",self.searchBar.text]];

NSLog(@"Filterd Array:-%@",fileterArray);
```

Comment: I do it, but still I have error, could you help me, where can i make mistake? http://pastebin.com/AfiG2uQK

Comment: -[UITableView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b9de000

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with JS,you should use [JSContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSContext_Ref/).It will look like:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.jsContext = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    self.jsContext[@"phrase"] = self;
    self.jsContext.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *context, JSValue *exceptionValue) {
        context.exception = exceptionValue;
        NSLog(@"exception：%@", exceptionValue);
    };
}
```

And then,add methods in your JS.